# R help: Error in checkarg_isintegerish() with qualtRics package

Tags: r, cran, qualtrics

I'm new to R and this isn't my code, and my predecessor didn't leave any documentation so I'm at a loss here.

I'm working with the qualtRics package in R, and I'm encountering an error related to the checkarg_isintegerish() function. The error message I'm receiving is as follows:

Error in `checkarg_isintegerish()`:
! Error in argument 'limit':
• Argument must be a single integer or integer-like numeric

Seems pretty self-explanatory, but I've searched my code for the word "limit," and there are no instances of it. It appears that this error is originating from within the qualtRics package or a function call within the package. I'm not sure how to resolve this issue. Any help/suggestions appreciated.

Code author had a tendency to place quotes around integers and that has caused errors in the past. What is really throwing me off is that I can't find a "limit" function anywhere to narrow down the issue.

Comment: The problem is with an argument named `limit`, not a function. Without a *reproducible* example, there is little we can do to help.

Comment: You should be looking at the documentation of the named function. You may not see a named argument “limit”. R allows positional matching of arguments. If the package authors added an argument in a later version that could explain the new error. If it’s proprietary code , you may need a consultant to bring you up to speed.

Comment: How do you know the code **ever** worked?   In all seriousness, I recommend you (a) write your own code from scratch, and (b) submit the existing code to thedailywtf.com

Comment: But in the meantime,  run that code, and when it exits with that error message,  type `traceback()`  to find out which called function threw the error.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Fair point--I actually have no way of knowing if this ever worked or was just still in development. What's the etiquette here, is it frowned upon to share code (as someone else suggested) and ask for help troubleshooting?